# AirplayUIAgent frequently asking to access Keychain

Tags: macos, appletv, airplay

Every time I open my Macbook I encounter a pop up saying that `AirplayUIAgent` wants to access confidential information stored in my keychain under "Lukes Apple TV"

Does anybody know what this process is? Should I just give it access? I have googled around and can find my question on Apple Support forums but nobody has ever answered it.